# Batch flatten subdirectorie in multiple files but keep file within

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple folders (over 1000)  with this structure:

```
/somemoviename
 /extrafanart
  /fanart1.jpg
```

I wish them all to look like this

```
/somemoviename
/fanart1.jpg
```

I have tried to do this via a program called fileboss but I dont think it can manage it. If anyone can show me how to do this with a .bat file I'd be most grateful as I'm ripping what hair I have left out of my head!.

Thanks

Comment: Which bits are constant?  How many files are in /extrafanart/? do they all need to move?

Comment: /somemoviename - not constant, they are all named respective of the movie. /extrafanart - every movie directory has this folder and within each "extrafanart" folder is "fanart1.jpg"

Comment: Desperate to get a bat file to do this! :(

Answer (score 0):

This batch file should be run in the folder where all the somemoviename folders are.

It's not tested though, but you can run it and it will print the first filename and then move the file from that folder, and then print `"Press any key to continue"` and pause.  When it pauses don't press any key but verify with explorer that the file has moved from the location it shows you to the correct folder, and then `put the file back where it came from`.  **Close the batch file by clicking on the X.** If it worked ok then it should be pretty safe to remove the pause statement and run it for real.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( ' dir fanart1.jpg /b /s /a-d ' ) do (
   pushd "%%~dpa"
      echo "%%a"
      move fanart1.jpg ..
      pause
   popd
)
```

Comment: Hi Fixidrive, Firstly I really appreciate you helping me with this. I tried the batch file it flashes up the cmdline interface for a second then nothing...

Comment: Where the movies folders are: C:\Users\myname\Desktop\New folder\-=Film Archive=- - This is actually a test folder on my desktop

Comment: Hold on! my bad, I just realised I batch renamed the fanart1.jpg's to fanart.jpg

Comment: Ok, I've run the bat file in the directory where all the movie folderes are, its moved the fanart.jpg into that directory rather than somemoviename dir. What I need is for each of the .jpg's moved into the main directory of the movie name.

Comment: I really should have searched more, this is exactly what I was after YAY!

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /A:D /S /B "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\New folder\films\*"') do (
    for %%y in ("%%a\*.jpg") do (
        call :GETPARENTPARENT "%%y" ret

        echo ret=!ret!
        move /Y "%%y" "!ret!"
    )
)

goto:EOF

:GETPARENTPARENT
set fileP=%1
echo received=%fileP%
for %%a in (%fileP%) do (
    set parent=%%~dpa
    cd !parent!\..
    set PPPath=!cd!
    for %%x in ("!PPPath!") do (
        set "%~2=%%~dpnx"
    )
)
GOTO:EOF

Comment: You were supposed to test it - I went to the effort of giving instructions.  I see where the error was - fixed now.

Comment: Thanks foxidrive for helping me out much appreciated